# Light Intensity calculations

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl

I had a doubt w.r.t Light calculations.

In  all the lighting calculation example I've seen, 
Light Intensity (defined as  LightIntensity = DiffuseContribution * diffuse + SpecularContribution * spec;) is calculated in ModelView Space.
gl_Position that is sent out is calculated in ModelView Projection space.

In the Fragment Shader, fragments are in 2D co-ordinates (and is a function of gl_Position).
The Light Intensity (calculated in Vertex shader) is applied directly to the Fragment.

My doubt is : In Fragment shader the Fragments are calculated after 
Model View Projection -> Viewport Transformation

Whereas Lighting Intensity is in

Model View -> ViewPort Transformation.

How is possible to directly apply the LightIntensity to the fragment ?

Comment: @Rabbid76 In the Vertex Shader Light intensity at the vertex is calculated in ModelView Space, whereas gl_Position is calculated in ModelView Projection Space. gl_Position is passed to Fragment Shader. 

In Fragment Shader, the LightIntensity is directly used to calculate the color at the Pixel. Note however that this LightIntensitry has been calculated in Model View Space (and not in ModelView Projection Space). Hence how can it be directly used.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I'm beginning to see your point. Is it correct that the only function of gl_Position is to obtain the ClipVolume